# Make size of arrows all the same in matplotlib quiver plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want make the arrow sizes all the same in a 2D [quiver plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). In the data files they are different sizes:

```
U = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/u.txt")
V = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/v.txt")
```

Main code here:

```
nx, ny = 240, 426

x1 = range(nx)
y1 = range(ny)

#data
U = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/u.txt")
V = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/v.txt")
            
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)  # `plot_surface` expects `x` and `y` data to be 2D
            
fig, hf = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hf.set_title("Model G fluid velocity vector field - every 5th arrow, time = " + str(c1))
Q = hf.quiver(X1[::5, ::5], Y1[::5, ::5], U[::5, ::5], V[::5, ::5], units='width',
      pivot='mid', scale=0.1, headwidth=7)#pivot='mid', units='inches')
qk = hf.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, r'$\frac{distance}{time}$', labelpos='E',
      coordinates='figure')
hf.scatter(X1[::5, ::5], Y1[::5, ::5], color='r', s=5)

plt.savefig('/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/plots/2D_video40/2D_video_velocity_' + str(c1) + '.png')
```

A screenshot of output video-plot looks like this:

[image]

@ [Quiver matplotlib : arrow with the same sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922866/quiver-matplotlib-arrow-with-the-same-sizes) Derek Eden, uses the following code to make the arrow sizes all the same for random `u` and `v`. How can I adapt this for non-random stored data?

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
u = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(9,9))
v = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(9,9))
plt.quiver(xx, yy, u, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by normalising the data with `U1`, `V1` and normalise factor `F`:

```
U = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/u.txt")
V = np.loadtxt("/home/brendan/software/tf2-model-g/arrays/quiver_array33/v.txt")

N = np.sqrt( U**2 + V**2 )  # normalize data
U1, V1 = U/N, V/N

#F = 0.001 # normalisation factor
F = 0.004

U1 *= F
V1 *= F

X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)  # `plot_surface` expects `x` and `y` data to be 2D

fig, hf = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hf.set_title("Model G fluid velocity vector field - every 5th arrow, time = " + str(c1))
Q = hf.quiver(X1[::5, ::5], Y1[::5, ::5], U1[::5, ::5], V1[::5, ::5], units='width',
     pivot='mid', scale=0.1, headwidth=5)
qk = hf.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, r'$\frac{distance}{time}$', labelpos='E',
     coordinates='figure')
hf.scatter(X1[::5, ::5], Y1[::5, ::5], color='c', s=0)
```

Resulting image of plot with same size vector arrows:
[image]